# (De)Serializing in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, xmlserializer

I have written a class (containing only properties). The code is shortened, here is only the part of the code what I want to do:

```
    Public Class test
        Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
            'Das Objekt lebensmittel serialisieren
            Dim ser As New Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(Me.GetType)
            Dim sw As New IO.StringWriter
            ser.Serialize(sw, Me)
            Return sw.tostring
        End Function

    Public Sub New()

    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal t As String)
        Dim deser As New Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(Me.GetType)
        Dim ms As New IO.MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(t))
        Me = CType(deser.Deserialize(ms), test) 'This throws an error
    End Sub
End Class
```

What I want to do is to overload the New() operator and deserialize the string to this class, like:

```
Dim x As New test(string)
```

How can I do this? The marked line throws an error in Sub New.

Comment: Have you considered a static method that just returns you the deserialised object? `Dim newObj = Test.FromXml(xmlString)`

Comment: Sounds like it is similar to my New() version. Remember, the deserialised object is a string (stored in a sqlite database). I have no idea how to implement your solution, nether my solution. That is the goal. (Btw: There were a definition too much, I edited the code).

Comment: Just take your current solution and change `Public Sub New` to `Public Shared Function FromXml` and change the last line to `Return CType(deser.Deserialize(ms), test)` and you're good to go.

Comment: Well the issue is that you're trying to assign something to `Me`. Deserialising into a new object is fine, but I'm suggesting having a function that returns an object from the XML, avoiding the self-assignment in `Me`. Thanks for explaining @VisualVincent

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_(object-oriented_programming)

Comment: Thank you Visual Vincent, this works! +1